# Got HTTP 503 – Service Unavailable error while updating to Craft 3

Tags: craft3, upgrades

1) Updated existing Craft 2 from the Control Panel

2) `.env`

```
DB_DRIVER="mysql"
DB_SERVER="localhost"
DB_USER="root"
DB_PASSWORD="pwd"
DB_DATABASE="dbname"
DB_SCHEMA="public"
DB_TABLE_PREFIX="some_"
DB_PORT=""
```

3 ) `/var/www/html/somename/config/general.php`

```
<?php

return [
    // Global settings
    '*' => [
        'defaultWeekStartDay' => 1,

        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,

        'cpTrigger' => 'admin',

        'securityKey' => getenv('SECURITY_KEY'),


        'useProjectConfigFile' => true,
    ],
    // Dev environment settings
    'dev' => [
        'devMode' => true,
        'useCompressedJs' => false,
        'allowUpdates' => true,
        'environmentVariables' => [
            'basePath' => '/var/www/html/craftcms3/web/',
            'baseUrl'  => 'http://craftcms3.local/',
        ],
        'siteUrl' => 'http://craftcms3.local/',
    ],

    // Staging environment settings
    'staging' => [
        // Prevent administrative changes from being made on staging
        'allowAdminChanges' => false,
    ],

    // Production environment settings
    'production' => [
        // Prevent administrative changes from being made on production
        'allowAdminChanges' => false,
    ],
];
```

4) and followed other mentioned steps at https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/upgrade.html#performing-the-upgrade

> Permission at root:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data  -R *
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Error when I hit http://craftcms3.local/admin

```
craft\web\ServiceUnavailableHttpException in /var/www/html/craftcms3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php:689
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/craftcms3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(223): craft\web\Application->_processUpdateLogic(Object(craft\web\Request))
#1 /var/www/html/craftcms3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#2 /var/www/html/craftcms3/web/index.php(22): yii\base\Application->run()
#3 {main}
```

> Till now I haven't installed any plugins in Craft 3

Update:

I tried again by following all steps above got the DB UPDATE screen after long time my system freezes now i got this error.

```
Database Exception: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'locale' in 'craft_categorygroups_i18n'
The SQL being executed was: ALTER TABLE `craft_categorygroups_i18n` ADD `siteId` int(11) AFTER `locale`

Migration: craft\migrations\m160807_144858_sites

Output:

> execute SQL: SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0 ... done (time: 0.000s)
> dropping {{%sites}} if it exists ... done (time: 0.271s)
> create table {{%sites}} ... done (time: 0.385s)
> create unique index craft_sites_handle_unq_idx on {{%sites}} (handle) ... done (time: 0.343s)
> create index craft_sites_sortOrder_idx on {{%sites}} (sortOrder) ... done (time: 0.284s)
> insert into {{%sites}} ... done (time: 0.041s)
> update in {{%userpermissions}} ... done (time: 0.004s)
> add column siteId integer AFTER `locale` to table {{%categorygroups_i18n}} ...Exception: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'locale' in 'craft_categorygroups_i18n'
The SQL being executed was: ALTER TABLE `craft_categorygroups_i18n` ADD `siteId` int(11) AFTER `locale` (/var/www/html/craftcms3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php:664)
#0 /var/www/html/craftcms3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php(1295): yii\db\Schema->convertException(Object(PDOException), 'ALTER TABLE `cr...')
#1 /var/www/html/craftcms3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php(1091): yii\db\Command->internalExecute('ALTER TABLE `cr...')
#2 /var/www/html/craftcms3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Migration.php(377): yii\db\Command->execute()
#3 /var/www/html/craftcms3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/migrations/m160807_144858_sites.php(547): yii\db\Migration->addColumn('{{%categorygrou...', 'siteId', Object(craft\db\mysql\ColumnSchemaBuilder))
#4 /var/www/html/craftcms3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/migrations/m160807_144858_sites.php(150): craft\migrations\m160807_144858_sites->addSiteColumn('{{%categorygrou...', 'siteId', true, 'locale')
#5 /var/www/html/craftcms3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/db/Migration.php(56): craft\migrations\m160807_144858_sites->safeUp()
#6 /var/www/html/craftcms3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/db/MigrationManager.php(243): craft\db\Migration->up(true)
#7 /var/www/html/craftcms3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/db/MigrationManager.php(163): craft\db\MigrationManager->migrateUp(Object(craft\migrations\m160807_144858_sites))
#8 /var/www/html/craftcms3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Updates.php(215): craft\db\MigrationManager->up()
#9 /var/www/html/craftcms3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/BaseUpdaterController.php(521): craft\services\Updates->runMigrations(Array)
#10 /var/www/html/craftcms3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/UpdaterController.php(209): craft\controllers\BaseUpdaterController->runMigrations(Array, 'restore-db')
#11 [internal function]: craft\controllers\UpdaterController->actionMigrate()
#12 /var/www/html/craftcms3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#13 /var/www/html/craftcms3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#14 /var/www/html/craftcms3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Controller.php(109): yii\base\Controller->runAction('migrate', Array)
#15 /var/www/html/craftcms3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(528): craft\web\Controller->runAction('migrate', Array)
#16 /var/www/html/craftcms3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(297): yii\base\Module->runAction('updater/migrate', Array)
#17 /var/www/html/craftcms3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(683): craft\web\Application->runAction('updater/migrate')
#18 /var/www/html/craftcms3/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(223): craft\web\Application->_processUpdateLogic(Object(craft\web\Request))
#19 /var/www/html/craftcms3/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(386): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#20 /var/www/html/craftcms3/web/index.php(22): yii\base\Application->run()
#21 {main}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the `web.log` file in `storage/logs/` for more details on why the error is happening? A 503 error could be because Craft is unable to connect to your database, for example.

Comment: You should ad the db port as well. This is 99% a db connection problem.
Do you need to make an ssl connection to your db? that's what I ran into.

Comment: I am doing this on my localhost, Currently i don't have access to my system, will add the available port and check. and suggested below i will check the log as well if it exists.